# DAX Formula Compare rows

Tags: sum, powerbi, dax

In the table below I have

```
Qty Price = DIVIDE(sum(Table A [Inv Value EUR]);SUM(Table A[fN Inv Qty]))

Cost of Material = IF(SUM(Table B[Open quantity]) > SUM(Table A [fN Inv Qty]);
                       sum(Table A[fN Inv Value EUR]);
                       [Qty Price]*sum(Table B[Open quantity]))


Total Qty = IF(sum(Table B[Open quantity])>SUM(Table A[fN Inv Qty]);
                sum(Table B[Open quantity]);
                SUM(Table A[fN Inv Qty]))
```

So the problem is I'm getting the Total wrong. I know that there is some problem in the formula but I don t know how to resolve it. Moreover, I would like that when I have a blank cell that was considered as 0.

In the Example, I should have as Total `Cost of Material` = 29767,16 €.

[image: image description here]

Comment: What is the measure of “fN Inv Qty”?

Comment: Open Qty, Fn Inv Qt, Total Inv Value € are just columns

Comment: It can’t be columns hence you have totals for them...